# Laravel query builder on many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

When using eloquent to select a model with many to many relationship, it's very simple like:

```
$orders = Order::with('products')->whereHas('products', function($query){
    $query->where('id', '=', 1);
});
```

This query will return all orders with the products for each order where order has a product with `id = 1`. When an order has many products, the query will return all products if order has a product with `id = 1`, 
but when using query builder to return the same result as eloquent, it's returning for each order just one product with `id = 1`.

Here is the query:

```
    DB::table('orders')->join( 'order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id' )
                    ->join( 'products', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id' )
                    ->whereIn('products.id', $this->products);
```

How to get all products for each order when order has a product with `id = 1` even when using `where` clause?

Comment: Only using subqueries